# Matlab point in polygon

Tags: javascript, c, matlab

Hi found this code on this [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test) and need help converting it to Matlab.

```
int pnpoly(int nvert, float *vertx, float *verty, float testx, float testy)
{
  int i, j, c = 0;
  for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
    if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
     (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
       c = !c;
  }
  return c;
}
```

**nvert**: Number of vertices in the polygon. Whether to repeat the first vertex at the end.

**vertx, verty**: Arrays containing the x- and y-coordinates of the polygon's vertices.

**testx, testy**: X- and y-coordinate of the test point. (This is from another Stack Overflow question: [Point in Polygon aka hit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test).

***JavaScript version:***

```
function insidePoly(poly, pointx, pointy) {
    var i, j;
    var inside = false;
    for (i = 0, j = poly.length - 1; i < poly.length; j = i++) {
        if(((poly[i].y > pointy) != (poly[j].y > pointy)) && (pointx < (poly[j].x-poly[i].x) * (pointy-poly[i].y) / (poly[j].y-poly[i].y) + poly[i].x) ) inside = !inside;
    }
    return inside;
}
```

How will this translate in **Matlab**:

```
function insidePoly = inpoly(poly, pointx, pointy)
% Code
% return inside
```

Comment: Hi my question is pretty simple and I provided a link to the original discussion. The first code is written in C, then someone created a JavaScript version of it. I want to implement it in Matlab and only asking for help to make the code matlab compatible.

Comment: Your question is not simple because you don't explain your problem implementing these functions. Do you understand what the code does? Where is your problem reimplementing this in M?

Comment: @Daniel so this is the [ray casting algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm) for finding whether a point (x,y) is inside a polygon or not. I am looking to rewrite this same function in matlab. Thanks!

Comment: You wrote that you want to implement it, thought this was some kind of assignment and you want to learn programming. Now you ask for an already existing implementation of a specific algorithm which was not mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab comes with a build-in function [inpolygon](http://en.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) which seems to do exactly what you are asking for. No need to reimplement it.

Comment: I am aware of that function but looking to implement this one in Matlab